# 'Default' value for value missing from result out of 5 possible values

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble of figuring to get things from db in a rather weird way. Say I have next table

```
ID  |   Rating
229 |   3
229 |   2
229 |   4
229 |   2
240 |   3
233 |   1
233 |   4
233 |   1
233 |   5
229 |   4
240 |   4
```

I need to result to look like

```
229 |   0,2,1,2,0
233 |   1,1,0,0,2
240 |   0,1,1,0,0
```

Basically. Rating varies between 1 and 5. I need 0 in 2nd column for each rating that id doesn't have. So for id 229 it's 0,2,1,2,0 because there are no 5 and 1 ratings for it, for 240 it's 0,1,1,0,0 because there are no 5, 2 and 1 ratings. 
Currently I have query

```
select object_id, group_concat(qty order by rating desc) as qties
from (
select object_id, rating, count(rating) qty
from wp_fb_ratings
group by rating, object_id
) n
group by object_id
```

it selects what I need, except it doesn't "zero-fill" counts for missing ratings. Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Look into LEFT JOIN and CASE statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with next query

```
select ID, group_concat(COALESCE(cnt,0) order by Rating desc) as rating_count
from 
(select distinct ID, tu.Rating from wp_fb_ratings join (
select 1 Rating union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 
) tu ) t1
left join (select ID, Rating, count(*) cnt from wp_fb_ratings 
group by ID, Rating) t2 using(ID, Rating) 
group by ID
```

On table with around 75k rows, it takes 0.5 seconds to execute, while query from @peterm answer took more than 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```sql
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(rating_count ORDER BY rating DESC) rating_count
  FROM
(
  SELECT l.id, l.rating, COUNT(r.rating) rating_count
    FROM
  (
    SELECT id, rating
      FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT id 
        FROM wp_fb_ratings
    ) d CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT 1 rating UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 
    ) a
  ) l LEFT JOIN wp_fb_ratings r
      ON l.id = r.id
     AND l.rating = r.rating
  GROUP BY l.id, l.rating
) q
 GROUP BY id
```

Output:

```
|  id | rating_count |
|-----|--------------|
| 229 |    0,2,1,2,0 |
| 233 |    1,1,0,0,2 |
| 240 |    0,1,1,0,0 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccf5d/12)** demo

Comment: Thank you, this works, but is there, more 'elegant' solution so to say?